# Second text render does not show when hit action button in Unreal Engine 4

Tags: unreal-4

I am basically making a system to show texts like "E to Open" when player gets close to a chest or door. I use this:

[image]

When I hit first chest, everything's fine but second or any other text won't show after that.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also, when I hit action button outside of trigger, texts don't show up at all.